# Find top entries from related subdocuments' arrays in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design, nosql

I have decided to try and use MongoDB for the back end server for a game I'm working on, but I don't have a background in database design or setup. That said, the database seems to be fairly basic with most transactions being simple update or find queries.

A boiled down version of my schema is this (In reality my _id is numeric and guaranteed unique, perfect for an index):

```
users_collection
{
    _id: 11111,
    nameFirst: "Bilbo",
    nameLast: "Baggins"
    friends: [222222,3333333,444444],
    userScores:[
        { level: "OtherGameType", scores: 
            [{score: 150},{score: 250},{score: 350}] },
        { level: "Level1", scores: [{score: 200}] },
        { level: "Level2", scores: [{score: 200}] }
    ]
}
```

My issue is I can't find a good way to pull a list of the top X scores for a given level from all of that user's friends. Ultimately, I would like the output to be something like this:

```
[   {nameFirst:"Martin", nameLast:"Freeman", score:2012},
    {nameFirst:"Ian", nameLast:"Holm", score:2001},
    {nameFirst:"Norman", nameLast:"Bird", score:1978}   ]
```

What's the best way to go about this?

One concern is someone could have a very large number of friends (500? 1000?), each with a list of 20 or 50 scores for a certain level (while other levels will only track one to 3 scores). I realize databases often work in terms of millions, but I'm nervous this could impact performance if this is a common call from the clients.

As an aside, I'm connecting to the server in Node.js (on the same server) and the target devices connecting to it will be browsers and mobile devices via REST requests. That said, I'm quite willing to restructure the schema or push certain computations to different layers if necessary or advised. All constructive criticisms welcome!

**tl;dr:** With DB redesign being an option, how can I retrieve a list of the top X scores from a given user's friends?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model does not seem to bad in consideration. You have all the scores attached to a user and a list of friends attached. Provided this does not get too huge this should be okay, and it gives you a lot of what you need in single read/write operations.

But looking at the important parts, let's get the information you want. So you are going to need a *list* of the friends at some point and you already have one in the document:

```
{

    _id: 11111,
    friends: [222222,3333333,444444],
    userScores:[
        { level: "OtherGameType", scores: 
        [{score: 150},{score: 250},{score: 350}] },
        { level: "Level1", scores: [{score: 200}] },
        { level: "Level2", scores: [{score: 200}] }
    ]

}
```

So given a certain user, with a document already retrieved into a variable called `user`,  you can query back on the collection using there friends list, using [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.users.aggregate([
    // Match all the friends and try to filter out results that have no
    // score for that level. Keeping the set size down
    { "$match": { 
       "_id": { "$in": user.friends }
       "userScores.level": "Level1",
    }},

    // Unwind the userScores
    { "$unwind": "$userScores" },

    // Really filter out the level that does not match
    { "$match": { "userScores.level": "Level1" } },    

    // Unwind the scores per level for the remaining results
    { "$unwind": "$scores"},

    // Group by user ("friend") to find the top scores
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id",
        "topScore": { "$max": "$userScores.scores.score"}
    }},

    // Sort the results by topScore descending
    { "$sort": { "topScore": -1 } },

    // Optionally limit to "n" results
    { "$limit": 10 }

])
```

And there you basically have it. The top 10 scores (if there are that many) on a level for all of the users friends.

As for **all** your other questions, those are probably best presented as their own question in their own context. I know there is a temptation to ask everything at once, especially when you find someone answers, but you **will** get more meaningful responses by separating  them.

One final note on your schema though. While it should be fine for most things, I just want to point out that you have introduced nested arrays by having an inner list of scores inside the `userScores` array. What you need to be aware of is the limitations of updating these items with use of the [positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays).

That is something that can be worked around, but you should be aware of the issues.

Other worthwhile reading, is more on [aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) and more of the pipeline processes. It is something you are likely to use if you regularly want *statistic* type results like this.

Comment: Mea culpa, I guess I had been going around in circles long enough that it felt like one big question in my head! I do look forward to giving this a try. I had gotten as far as using a $match in the aggregate pipeline, but no matter how many times I read the docs and examples it wasn't clicking for me. I look forward to trying this out section by section as soon as I can. Thanks! Could you just clarify the bit where you said it'd be fine as long as it didn't get too big? You mean the collection or the friends arrays?

Comment: @squid808 There is a point where big arrays start to cause a degradation in performance. Big meaning in the 500's to 1000's range, but it would all depend on your usage and may not affect you for the type of data you are working with.